# Where to save a class that is being extended to another class in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Lab5 extends Lab4 implements ActionListner
```

Lab5 is the project I am working on now, and I need to extend the Lab4 class within my Lab5. My question is where do I need to save the Lab4 class so that Lab5 can access it. And is that all I need to transfer, the Lab4.class, or is there soemthing else that I need to put within the Lab5 as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Save it in a new file, Lab5.java

Comment: no matter, be careful to correct "import pa.ck.a.ge.Lab4;"

Answer (score 1):

If these classes are in the same `package` and you have sources of `Lab4` (`Lab4.java`) just compile them together (the compiler will find `Lab4.java`):

```
$ javac Lab5.java
```

If you have already compiled `Lab4.class` file, include it in the CLASSPATH during compilation:

```
$ javac -cp Lab4.class Lab5.java
```

If you want to have access to this class in your IDE, this class/JAR must be added as dependency/library.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Lab4.class? If it is in the same package you don't need to do anything. If its in some other package,
add `import package.Lab4;` in the top, where `package` is the package folder for `Lab4.class`.

Comment: They are separate projects, so the Lab4.class is in a folder named Lab4Project.

Comment: That is fine. Your `import` statement will be like `import Lab4Project.Lab4;`. If it doesn't work, open `Lab4.java` and share the `package` statement mentioned in the top of the file to understand your issue better.

Comment: Not very sure, `Lab4Project` is a different project or different folder in same project where you have `Lab5Project` folder. If `Lab4Project` different project, then make sure that `Lab4Project` `project/jar` is added in classpath of `Lab5Project`. If you want to know, how to do it then please let me know how are you trying to compile/execute i.e. through command line or some IDE such as `eclipe`.